# Recursion equation given in Handbook of Enumerative combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

I want to know if the following recursion formula which I found in the first part of the book "Handbook of enumerative combinatorics" is true and what may be an idea to approach it.

P$_\le$$_j$,$_\le$$_k$ (n)=P$_\le$$_j$,$_\le$$_{k-1}$ (n)+P$_\le$$_j$,$_\le$$_k$ (n-k)

Where P$_\le$$_j$,$_\le$$_k$ (n) is the number of partitions of n into at most j parts of size at most k.

I have thought about it, and I am having my doubts on whether it is true or not, since I used a specific example with n=15 (unless I have a mistake somewhere) and it did not work.

What I did was the following.

For n=15, I used j=4 and k=8. The partitions which I obtained where as follow:

1+1+5+8$\quad$ 2+2+4+7$\quad$ 2+6+7

1+1+6+7$\quad$ 2+2+5+6$\quad$ 3+4+8

1+2+4+8$\quad$ 2+3+3+7$\quad$ 3+5+7

1+2+5+7$\quad$ 2+3+4+6$\quad$ 3+6+6

1+2+6+6$\quad$ 2+3+5+5$\quad$ 4+4+7

1+3+3+8$\quad$ 2+4+4+5$\quad$ 4+5+6

1+3+4+7$\quad$ 3+3+3+6$\quad$ 5+5+5

1+3+5+6$\quad$ 3+3+4+5$\quad$ 7+8

1+4+4+6$\quad$ 1+6+8

1+4+5+5$\quad$ 1+7+7

2+2+3+8$\quad$ 2+5+8

I know that P$_\le$$_j$,$_\le$$_{k-1}$ (n)=P$_\le$$_4$,$_\le$$_{8-1}$ (15) are the partitions which do not include the 8, and there are in total 8 partitions which DO include the 8, but when I find P$_\le$$_4$,$_\le$$_8$ (15-8)=P$_\le$$_4$,$_\le$$_8$ (7), I get that there are in total 11 partitions of 7 into at most 4 parts of size at most 8.

If there is a mistake on this recursion expression, I would really appreciate it for some one to let me know what will the real recursion look like and why, because I looked at a similar problem where somebody had already asked about a recursion expression for the total number of partitions of n into k distinct parts of size at most M, but in the book I am looking at, I am given the recursion I mentioned for a different scenario.

I am learning combinatorics on my own and maybe I am just overthinking this.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to count partitions of $n$ with at most $j$ parts, each $\le k$.
For such a partition, there are two cases:

- None of the parts is of size $k$.  The number of these is $P_{\le j, \le k-1}(n)$.
- The largest part is of size $k$.  You can get such a partition by taking a partition of $n-k$ with at most $j-1$ parts, each of size $\le k$, and adding a new part of size $k$; and all such partitions can be obtained in this way.  So the number of these is $P_{\le j-1, \le k}(n-k)$.

So the formula should be

$$ P_{\le j, \le k}(n) = P_{\le j, \le k-1}(n) + P_{\le j-1, \le k}(n-k) $$
which is not quite what you wrote.

Comment: Thank you so much Robert. I understand what you did, how I wrote it is exactly how it appears in the book. I see that it has a mistake, and I appreciate you letting me know how the real recursion should look like.